# Is there a universally accepted way to refer to choosing a more powerful motor for an application?

Tags: motors, sales, communication

One antonym word I can think of is "derating".  If I say "derate motor for pump X", it can mean "select a motor with lower power output, since the pump doesn't need a more powerful motor".

But what about selecting a more powerful motor?  How can I say "I want to ____ the motor for this pump" and mean "up" the motor, "bump up" the motor, "choose-a-stronger" motor?

I am looking for a phrase or single word, that can be used to speak of this concept clearly.  For example when explaining the concept to the sales team or to the customer (user of the engineering application).

Comment: Is [this](http://www.camaro5.com/forums/attachment.php?s=7983531c3df9f6130889230ae209cfc7&attachmentid=700609&stc=1&d=1426351396) not the answer you're looking for?

Comment: How about "higher margin". All you doing increasing the margin of operation.

Comment: Actually, your definition of "derating" is backwards. When you derate a component, you select one that has specifications *greater* than what the application nominally needs, in order to increase the operating margins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite sure the word used is "oversized". When you say to an engineer that a motor is oversized for that application (for that pump) the engineer will not think the motor dimensions are too big (and will not fit) but he will understand as the motor rated values would exceed the minimum requirements by an unexpected high amount. The context of the conversation will clarify if you mean "oversized" as a good thing (heavy-duty) or as a bad thing (waste of money, energy, space or even security compromise in the case the motor can destroy the pump for example).